# Execution failed for task ':libimgur:kaptKotlin'

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, kapt

first of hi, i recently started working with kotlin, so i am working in my first project and this error is giving me hard time

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':libimgur:kaptKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iswfU.png)

i have checked my kotlin plugin and android studio version and other required updates, they are all updated.